# Multithreading with python.net

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I am calling python from C# using the following code:

```
if (!PythonEngine.IsInitialized)
{
    PythonEngine.Initialize();
    PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads();
}
//var pythonScriptCommand = string.Format("{0}", Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "scripts" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "keyringtest.py")); //Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "PythonSampleSystemDiagnostic.py");

IntPtr gs = PythonEngine.AcquireLock();

using (PyScope scope = Py.CreateScope())
{

    //foreach (var array in myCommand.Settings)
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", array)); ;
    //}
        string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(@"../../Source/AMD.Agent.Standard.DataExchange/Commands/PythonScripts/", ScriptName));
        var file = PythonEngine.Compile(fileContent);

        scope.Execute(file);
        //dynamic accessToken = scope.Get("get_access_token");
    dynamic dataExtract = scope.Get("get_result_http");

    //_logger.Info(myCommand.Settings.ToString()   + "123123123123");
    var dict = myCommand.Settings.ToDictionary(x => x.SettingName, x => x.SettingValue);
    var dict123 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
    dataExtract(token,url1,"PerformanceHistoryPeriod");
    //Console.WriteLine(_apxApiService + "123123123123123");
}

PythonEngine.ReleaseLock(gs);
PythonEngine.Shutdown();
```

Referenced this link:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythondotnet/2010-December/001058.html

I am not sure how this works in the sense that if I call this code multiple times in different threads, do all the script executions run in parallel or do they run sequentially, based on the lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can execute multiple threads simultaneously with Python.NET due to the [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). You can still execute python code in the separate thread, just not multiple threads at the same time (at least as it stands for now).

An alternative would be using [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/), which provides a .NET implementation of Python 2 syntax - it can execute code in multiple threads just fine.

You can read a bit more information about pros and cons of using Python.NET versus IronPython here:

https://www.alternetsoft.com/blog/python-net-iron-python-scripting